# Is there anything like Fiddler for debugging HTTP interaction on iOS7?

Tags: ios, http, debugging, fiddler

If I'm not sure that my Windows application sends correct HTTP requests I use Fiddler and can see all the headers and the data transferred and the server response - lots of useful data.

Is there a similar tool for iOS7?

Comment: @Amar: I'm not sure that any tool suitable for OS X is suitable for iOS.

Comment: Usually network related debugging is done for iOS simulator on your MAC using Wireshark or other s/w. There are no app store approved apps available to do this for iOS. This may be achievable on a jailbreak device but not sure which apps.

Comment: Worth a read: [Remote Packet Capture for iOS Devices](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/02/07/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices.html)

Comment: It is a duplicate, because you set the iOS device to proxy all requests through the mac, then read everything on the mac. I use Charles for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to debug HTTP traffic.

Comment: Does it run right on the device just as Fiddler runs on the same computer as the program being debugged?

Comment: @sharptooth No, it does not run on iPhone/iPad devices. Check for [more here](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/10010/can-wireshark-be-installed-on-an-ipad-or-iphone)

Comment: It doesn't run on the iOS, but if you're debugging with the simulator it does what you want. Otherwise you'd need to set your device to use a Mac for networking.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to debug Http traffic.